# Issue comparing timestamp with date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In my query I need to return only those records that are greater than another date, returned by the function. The field I am comparing is a timestamp and the date function returns is a of type DATE.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE MY_TIMESTAMP > MyFunction1('Test Date');
```

when I am comparing two values where only time differs slightly - in munutes or seconds, the comparison does not work.

For example when

```
MY_TIMESTAMP=11/27/2018 12:15:42.000000 PM -05:00
```

and

```
MyFunction1('Test Date') returns 11/27/2018 12:22:00 PM
```

no record should be returned from TABLE1 for that ID but the record does get returned. What can I do to make the comparison more granular?

Comment: The timestamp is taking the time zone into affect.  You would need to perform some operation to get rid of the time zone -- but I assume it is there for a reason.

Comment: A `timestamp` does not have a time zone.  A `timestamp with time zone` or a `timestamp with local time zone` does.  Your example shows a time zone so I'm guessing that `my_timestamp` is a `timestamp with time zone` but the answer is slightly different in the three different cases.

Comment: the type is TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE

Answer (score 0):

From [Datetime and Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG250)

> Oracle Database performs all timestamp arithmetic in UTC time. For
>   `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data, Oracle Database converts the
>   datetime value from the database time zone to UTC and converts back to
>   the database time zone after performing the arithmetic. For `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data, the datetime value is always in UTC, so no
>   conversion is necessary.

If you provide a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value (i.e. value without any time zone information) then Oracle attaches the `SESSIONTIMEZONE` to this value and then it does the comparison based on UTC.

Attaching `SESSIONTIMEZONE` to input value might be correct or not, it depends on your current session and content of `MyFunction1`

Comment: MyFunction1 returns a value of type DATE: `1/27/2018 12:22:00 PM`